# Generic Cast, casting a int to double not possible

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a dictionary that stores different types of variables (string, double, int, etc.), they are stored as objects.

I have a generic Set method and a generic get method.

```
private static Dictionary<int, object> dict = new Dictionary<int, object>();

public static void Set<T>(int key, object value)
{
    dict.Add(key, (T)value);
}

public static T Get<T>(int key)
{
    dict.TryGetValue(key, out object value);
    return (T)value;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Set<int>(1, 100);
    Get<double>(1);
}
```

In the Main I'm trying to save the variable 100 as integer, which works, it is stored "as an object" in the dictionary. 
Now when trying to Get the variable, casting it to double, the IllegalCastException is thrown, but why?
A explicit cast from object to double is available, as well as a explicit cast from int to double.

Comment: Why not just use `double` instead of `object`? Or maybe `string`. What types you plan to store as value?

Comment: Casting is different from converting. You are trying to convert an `int` to a `double`. Casting means keeping the XXX the same, but just show it to me as a YYY.

Comment: @Enigmativity - as Eric Lippert once [pointed out](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/) cast does two different things that are opposites of each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't *cast* from `object` to `int` or to `double`. You [*unbox*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing). And the unboxing rules are clear - you can only take out exactly the same type as you put in. (Insert some caveats around enums and underlying types which aren't exactly relevant to the question at hand)

> For the unboxing of value types to succeed at run time, the item being unboxed must be a reference to an object that was previously created by boxing an instance of that value type. Attempting to unbox `null` causes a [`NullReferenceException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullreferenceexception). Attempting to unbox a reference to an incompatible value type causes an [`InvalidCastException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidcastexception).